# How Do I Insert Into a Table With Row Level Security?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, row-level-security

I have the following table:

```
            Table "api_v1.person"
    Column     |  Type  |      Modifiers
---------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------
 person_id     | bigint | not null default...
 name          | text   | not null
 date_of_birth | date   |
 api_user      | text   | not null default "current_user"()
```

That has the following policy:

```
POLICY "api_user_only" FOR ALL
  USING ((api_user = ("current_user"())::text))
  WITH CHECK ((api_user = ("current_user"())::text))
```

My understanding is that the `FOR ALL` portion of the policy means that it covers inserts and the `WITH CHECK` ensures that the value inserted into api_user is the same as the current user, eg the role name.  The `USING` clause should only effect SELECTS or other data that is returned. However, when I try to insert I get the following results:

```
demo=> INSERT INTO api_v1.person (name, api_user) VALUES ('Greg', current_user);
ERROR:  query would be affected by row-level security policy for table "person"
```

How do I do this insert?

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6.8.

Here is the SQL necessary to reproduce:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE SCHEMA api_v1;

CREATE TABLE api_v1.person (
    person_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE,
    api_user TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT current_user
);

ALTER TABLE api_v1.person ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY
api_user_only
ON
    api_v1.person
USING
    (api_user = CURRENT_USER)
WITH CHECK
    (api_user = CURRENT_USER)
;

CREATE ROLE test_role;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA api_v1 TO test_role;
GRANT ALL ON api_v1.person TO test_role;
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE api_v1.person_person_id_seq TO test_role;

COMMIT;

SET ROLE test_role;

INSERT INTO api_v1.person ("name") VALUES ('Greg');
```

Comment: I tried your example, and it works on my PostgreSQL v10. Can you extend the question to include a complete example that exhibits the behavior (complete SQL statements, please)?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have added the complete SQL statements to reproduce this issue.  Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: When I run your example on v10 and 9.6, I get the error `ERROR:  permission denied for sequence person_person_id_seq`. This is not related to row level security and is fixed by `GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE api_v1.person_person_id_seq TO test_role;`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So I granted usage on that sequence and switched roles to test_role and I still get the `ERROR:  query would be affected by row-level security policy for table "person"` message.  I can insert as a super user, but not the test_role.

Comment: I've also tested on a clean install of PostgreSQL 10.3 and get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting in postgresql.conf, `row_security`.  If this is set to off then any query that would be effected by a row level security policy fails with the error: `ERROR:  query would be affected by row-level security policy for table "table_name"`.  However, queries from superusers, the table owner (if you don't force RLS), and roles with bypassrls will work.

The `row_security` setting needs to be set to `on` and then PostgreSQL needs to be restarted for regular user statements to be processed against tables with row level security policies.

From the source code:

```
/*
 * We should apply RLS.  However, the user may turn off the row_security
 * GUC to get a forced error instead.
 */
if (!row_security && !noError)
    ereport(ERROR,
            (errcode(ERRCODE_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGE),
             errmsg("query would be affected by row-level security policy for table \"%s\"",
                    get_rel_name(relid)),
             amowner ? errhint("To disable the policy for the table's owner, use ALTER TABLE NO FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY.") : 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems that EDB installers set this to `on` by default. Was your server installed in an alternative way?

Comment: @klin I installed from the PostgreSQL apt repository using an Ansible role named ANXS.postgresql.  I'm digging in a bit more to see if it was turned to off in that Ansible role.  If so, I'll raise that as a bug with them.  I may also raise an issue with PostgreSQL.  That error message wasn't helpful.

Comment: @klin Looks like the standard PostgreSQL repos also default to 'on' and this is an issue with the Ansible role.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked 9.5, 9.6 and 10 from EDB, also 10 from BigSql - all with `on`.